Do any of the recent serial terminal solutions (VersaTerm, FabGL Serial Terminal) support UTF-8?
I'm thinking about attaching a serial terminal (real iron!) to my Mixtile Cluster Box (with ASMedia ASM2824), whose control board is equipped with a (hidden) UART interface. As my VT420 has died, I'd like to pick a serial terminal board like the VersaTerm or the FabGL Serial Terminal. None of the two has stated UTF-8 support in the respective docs. As recent systems almost only support UTF-8, I'd like to know whether the two abovementioned (or some other serial terminal board) are compatible.
